# Access a new created line from another sub

Tags: vb6

I have some problems accessing informations from a new created element.This is my code

```
Private Sub c1_Click()
  Refresh
  Timer1.Enabled = Not Timer1.Enabled
  If Timer1.Enabled Then
    c1.Caption = "Stop"
  Else
    c1.Caption = "Start"
  End If
  a = l.X2 - l.X1
  choice = a
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim l As Line
  Set l = Controls.Add("VB.Line", "l", Me)
  With l
    .X1 = 2760
    .Y1 = 3000
    .X2 = 5640
    .Y2 = 3000
    .Visible = True
    .BorderStyle = 1
    .BorderWidth = 2
    .BorderColor = vbRed
  End With
End Sub
```

I get an error when i click the button:"Object required".On the form i can see the line but i can't access it from another sub.Where is the problem?

Comment: "On the form i can see the line but i can't access it from another sub."  As C-Pound Guru pointed out, you can't access it by the variable `l` unless you move that variable out to form level.  You can, however, access the control itself **by name** via the Controls collection with `Controls("l").xxx = yyy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Line` variable `l` is private to the `Form_Load` procedure and goes out of scope.

Move `Dim l As Line` from `Form_Load` to the top of your form's code module (outside of any method or function). This will make it available to any method or procedure on your form:

```
Dim l As Line

Private Sub c1_Click()
   Refresh
   Timer1.Enabled = Not Timer1.Enabled
   If Timer1.Enabled Then
      c1.Caption = "Stop"
   Else
      c1.Caption = "Start"
   End If
   a = l.X2 - l.X1
   choice = a
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
   Set l = Controls.Add("VB.Line", "l", Me)
    With l
     .X1 = 2760
     .Y1 = 3000
     .X2 = 5640
     .Y2 = 3000
     .Visible = True
     .BorderStyle = 1
     .BorderWidth = 2
     .BorderColor = vbRed
    End With
End Sub
```